# В чем разница между code и status?

Tags: php, yii2, исключения

при выбрасывании `throw new HttpException` есть возможно выкинуть не только статус и сообщение, но и код.

```
throw new HttpException(200, "OK", $code)
```

вопрос: зачем нужен этот параметр?

что в нем указывать: если код ответа, то что указывать в статусе?

Comment: Из какой библиотеки класс HttpException? В базовых исключениях php такого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.exception.php), в классе Exception есть атрибут code - код исключения. Соответственно, это такой код, который можно назначать любым исключениям, т.к. они все наследуются от Exception.

status же - это вещь, специфичная для http-запросов.

Comment: код исключения - т.е. типа 400, 404 и т.п.?

Comment: @dasauser нет. Этот код идет в родительский класс Exception. Он не имеет отношения к http запросу. По дефолту ему присваивается 0 и в классе Exception и в Yiiшном HttpException таким его лучше и оставить

Comment: @Григорий, ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Когда тебе в ответ приходит http-статус 404 - ты знаешь описание этого кода, "Page Not Found". Вот так и ты можешь делать, чтобы при каждой ошибке не писать всегда текст, придумать для каждого текстового исключения себе код ошибки.